# How to prevent users to delete files but allow to create subdirectories?

Tags: linux, ext4

I want to implement the following fs access model to the directory:

- user can read and execute "admin" files only,
- create and remove only own directories.

So if user wants to share data with others he/she creates new directory with appropiate permissions and puts files there.

Is it possible in ext4 or other file systems to do that?

Comment: This looks pretty much like using the home directory of each user (in most if not all Linux distros).

Comment: Regarding the "create and remove only own directories." This can be achieved using the sticky bit.

Comment: @Pier That works perfectly. Thank you.